# Laravel DB::transaction() return value

Tags: php, laravel

It's my first time to use `DB::transaction()` but how exactly does it work if a transaction fails or is successful? In the example below, do I have to manually assign a value to return `true`, or if it fails will the method either return `false` or totally exit the transaction (therefore skipping the rest of the code)? The docs aren't so helpful on this.

```
use Exception;
use DB;

try {
    $success = DB::transaction(function() {
        // Run some queries
    });

    print_r($success);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Uh oh.';
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By giving a look at `function transaction` it does its process inside a try/catch block

```
public function transaction(Closure $callback)
{
    $this->beginTransaction();

    // We'll simply execute the given callback within a try / catch block
    // and if we catch any exception we can rollback the transaction
    // so that none of the changes are persisted to the database.
    try
    {
        $result = $callback($this);

        $this->commit();
    }

    // If we catch an exception, we will roll back so nothing gets messed
    // up in the database. Then we'll re-throw the exception so it can
    // be handled how the developer sees fit for their applications.
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $this->rollBack();

        throw $e;
    }
```

So throws an Exception (after the rollback) if fails or returns `$result`, which is the result of your callback

Comment: Is there a way to simulate a failed transaction?

Comment: meaning u want to catch `catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Uh oh.';
}` ?

Comment: Sorry, no need. I momentarily forgot about `throw`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a short version if you want to use the default transaction method that ships with Laravel without handling it manually.

```
$result = DB::transaction(function () { 
    // logic here
    return $somethingYouWantToCheckLater;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following

```
DB::rollback();
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author, to move the solution to the answer space)*.

Since I was more concerned about returning a boolean value depending on the success of my query, with a few modifications it now returns `true/false` depending on its success:

```
use Exception;
use DB;

try {
  $exception = DB::transaction(function() {
    // Run queries here
  });

  return is_null($exception) ? true : $exception;

} catch(Exception $e) {
    return false;
}
```

Take note that the variable `$exception` is never returned since if something goes wrong with your query, the `catch` is immediately triggered returning `false`. Thanks to @ilaijin for showing that an `Exception` object is thrown if something goes wrong.